# Calculating stable orbital resonance and other factors into orbits

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, celestial-mechanics

Firstly here is a brief summary of what I trying to accomplish.

From a predetermined total solar system mass , star count in that system, per-star classification and mass I am building a system of calculating the stable orbits of all orbital bodies in that system.

I then calculate the number and mass (from the remaining solar mass) of each body,by the classifications:

Planet ,Moon,Planetoids, and other (This includes the total estimated mass of asteroid belts or rings etc).

Once all averages have been calculated for the system, additional modifiers are factored in - orbital effects/factors that are yet to be fully understood will be given an expected value and percentage modified based on pseudo random noise.

The question:

How do I calculate the minima/maxima stable orbital radius of a planet around star of M mass.

Suppose a moon is orbiting this planet, what factors derived from the star effect the orbit characteristics of the moon and what are calculations associated with the orbit limits.

The same applies for 'other' bodies.

Factors  I am looking to include from research thus far:

I.Orbital resonance (is it best factor in cosmological constant? -I have read some evidence shows this is no longer to be assumed a value of 0 -if so, would this have a significant effect on orbit properties).

II. Radiation pressure (E.g Yarkovsky effect, especially on 'other' bodies)

Note: external factors of the solar system do NOT need to be calculated due to the galaxy I am simulating being a largley static environment.

DMCA limits my reasons as to why, suffice to say I am from s primarily programming and electronics background.

I appreciate any advice, esp regarding  any suggested heuristic equations.

Comment: An example:
http://web.archive.org/web/20071213121121/http://www.geocities.com/area51/corridor/8611/mseqstar.htm